# Access cannot run the callback function 'GetEnabled'

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, ribbonx

Access is unable to locate my Sub 'GetEnabled'. I would like to have the button "bttnPAemail" disable unless the form rptPA is active. I cannot get Access to find the Sub 'GetEnabled'. I created a new module called 'ribbonXML' and stored the VBA below in it. Upon load, I get the callback error.

```
<button id="bttnPAemail" label="Email PA Report" onAction="oPAemail" imageMso="NewMailMessage"
size="large" supertip="Print" getEnabled="GetEnabled"/>
```

```vb
Option Compare Database
Public IRibbonControl As IRibbonUI

Public Sub GetEnabled(ctl As IRibbonControl, ByRef Enabled)
    If Reports!rptPA.Visible = True Then
        Enabled = True
    Else
        Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the "callback error"? Also you have `ctl As IRibbonControl` and then `ByRef Enabled`, are you sure that's the correct signature? `ctl` is implicitly `ByRef`, and `Enabled` is implicitly `As Variant`. Should it be `ByVal ctl As IRibbonControl` and `ByRef Enabled As Boolean`?

Comment: The error message is: "Microsoft Access cannot run the macro or callback function 'GetEnabled'. Make sure the macro or function exists and takes the correct parameters."

Comment: "and takes the correct parameters" seems to be the operative part in this case.

Comment: I've changed it to "Public Sub GetEnabled(ByVal ctl As IRibbonControl, ByRef Enabled As Boolean)" and still receive the same error.

Comment: The module is a standard procedural module? Do you have other callbacks? Are they in the same module? Where's `oPAemail`?

Comment: oPAemail is a Run Code Macro that is referencing the PAemail Function in my CustomRibbon module. The only way I could get the onAction portion to work was to link a Run Code Macro to a Function.

Comment: I've no idea what that means, but you probably want your `GetEnabled` callback in the same module.

Comment: Remove the "Public IRibbonControl As IRibbonUI" and check again your code...i have exactly the same code and works fine